# Toggling multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I can't seem to get jquery to toggle multiple checkboxes. I want to grab all the checkboxes on the page with a certain name and toggle them. Here is what I am currently trying but it just generates the error below and I am not sure why. What am I missing here?

```
$("input[name=recurringGridCheckbox]").prop("checked", !(this.prop("checked")));
```

> Object doesn't support property or method 'prop'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a syntax error in rhe variable you use in the setter; `this` refers to the DOMElement, not the jQuery object and so does not have the `prop()` method available.

To fix this you can provide a function to the `prop()` method which will update the property based on its current state. Try this:

```
$("input[name=recurringGridCheckbox]").prop("checked", function(i, checked) {
    return !checked;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.prop` is a jquery method, so you must use it with a jquery object:

```
$("input[name='recurringGridCheckbox']").prop("checked", !$(this).prop("checked") );
```

Also, in specific cases the attribute value needs to be enclosed in quotes, so it may be good practice to always do that.